# CakePHP - multiple paginated datasets on same page from same model

Tags: cakephp

I have an admin page that pulls data from my ExpenseClaim model. I want to have 3 different paginated tables, each table displaying data based on a different condition (a status). This is what I have (which doesn't work - nothing is paginated in the view) in my controller:

```
// Pending
$this->set('claims', $this->paginate('ExpenseClaim', array('ExpenseClaim.claim_status_id' => '2')));

// Get approved
$this->set('approvedClaims', $this->paginate('ExpenseClaim', array('ExpenseClaim.claim_status_id' => '3')));

// Get Declined
$this->set('declinedClaims', $this->paginate('ExpenseClaim', array('ExpenseClaim.claim_status_id' => '4')));
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this, I've do a fair amount of searching but only found things relating to different models or hacks using jquery plugins. Surely this can be done in cake alone?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Did you wrote the above code inside ExpenseClaimsController? But in case if you in another controller, make sure you have a paginate variable as the following

```
public $paginate = array(
   'ExpenseClaim' => array(
         .......
   )
);
```